# Making request to remote server from localhost getting preflight Request 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

Complete error is this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ip:port/path. Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Environment Details:

Exhausted tried almost everything, but can't accomplish task.

Actually I am requesting node.js server, from angular js client. I have tried all possible options.

Flow is in this way:

1. Request initiated from web portal designed in angular js.
2. Hit node.js server on remote machine.

What I have tried so for

[expressjs/cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) and 
[Solving "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in localhost NodeJS + Express](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUWcZ4FzgmI)

Client End Code

---

```
$scope.testFunc = function () {
    $("div#preloader").show();
    $http.post(rtcControlUrl, data).success(function () {
        $("div#preloader").hide();
        if(response.success)
            $.notify(response.msg, "success");
        else $.notify(response.msg);
        console.log(response.data);
    }).error(function () {
        $.notify("Request timeout!");
        $("div#preloader").hide();
    });
};

app.post("/path", cors(), function(req, res) {
           shelljs.exec("bash test.sh",{silent:true,async:false}).output;
                    console.log(output);
                    res.json({"success": true, msg: 'some text', 'data' : output});
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix this issue by using [NPM Request Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) with request header

```
{
   name : 'content-type',
   value: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
```

Now I resolved this issue without setting any header on server end code. I achieved this in three steps.

**Client**

```
$scope.testFunction= function () {
        $("div#preloader").show();
        $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
            $("div#preloader").hide();
            if(response.success)
                $.notify(response.msg, "success");
            else $.notify(response.msg);
            console.log(response.data);
        }).error(function () {
            $.notify("Request timeout!");
            $("div#preloader").hide();
        });
    };
```

**Local node server**

```
request({
        url    : url,
        method : "POST",
        json   : true,
        headers: [
            {
                name : 'content-type',
                value: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        ],
        body   : data
    }, function optionalCallback(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('**************[page][functionName][Request][Fail]*****************', err);
            res.json({success: false, msg: 'msg', data: err});
        } else {
            var dataObj = (response && response.body) ? response.body.data : undefined;
            console.info('*************************[pageName][functionName][Request][Success]**********************');
            res.json({success: true, msg: 'msg', data: ''});
        }
    });
```

**Remember on local node server headers in same way as described in** [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUWcZ4FzgmI)

End server upon which I am executing final business logic.

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.options('*', cors());
app.post("/path", cors(), function(req, res) {
           shelljs.exec("bash test.sh",{silent:true,async:false}).output;
                    console.log(output);
                    res.json({"success": true, msg: 'some text', 'data' : output});
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message says **Response to preflight request**.

If you look up [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) you will see that is uses the OPTIONS method.

> "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain

Your code:

> app.post("/path", cors()

… only uses the cors middleware on POST requests.

You need to handle the OPTIONS request too.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

Comment: I used OPTIONS request too. But it still not working

Comment: @ShahNawaz — Then you didn't set up options support correctly. Since the question doesn't include that code, we can't tell how.